# How does the R Survey package compute bootstrap confidence intervals?

Tags: r, sampling, survey, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I'm wondering how to use replication weights and the confint implementation of the survey package to construct bootstrap confidence intervals/standard errors.

Looking at the `survey` package's [implementation of confint](https://github.com/cran/survey/blob/master/R/confint.R), it seems as though it's simply taking the standard error of the `theta` list generated after replication, and multiplying it by the statistic corresponding to a given alpha range.

But that doesn't really correspond with any bootstrap implementation I'm aware of. Typically, you'd instead be using a percentile of the distribution of theta to get the sample mean's distribution's confidence interval. The T and BCa intervals are another matter.

Here is my R Code. I have not used the provided weights, instead letting `repweights` weights be generated as "sample with replacement" weights with equal probability.

```r
data(api)
d <- apiclus1 %>% select(fpc, dnum,api99)
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, data=d, fpc=~fpc)
rclus1<-as.svrepdesign(dclus1,type="bootstrap", replicates=100)
```

To test the confidence intervals, we can use:

```
test_mean <- svymean(~api99, rclus1)
confint(test_mean, df=degf(rclus1))
confint(test_mean, df=degf(rclus1)) - mean(d$api99)
```

Which results:

```
         2.5 %   97.5 %
api99 554.2971 659.6592
          2.5 %   97.5 %
api99 -52.68107 52.68107
```

So clearly the interval is symmetric, which defeats some of the purpose of using the bootstrap.

So let's try this:

```
test_bs <- withReplicates(rclus1, function(w, data) weighted.mean(data$api99, w), return.replicates=T)
```

This will bootstrap the replicates, where the weights are the repweights (which I assume are with replacement weights). Here are the intervals using BCa intervals on the replications:

```
bca(test$replicates) - mean(d$api99)
-43.2878  49.1148
```

Clearly not symmetric.

Using percentile intervals:

```
c(quantile(test$replicates, 0.025),quantile(test$replicates, 0.975))  - mean(d$api99)
     2.5%     97.5% 
-45.50944  48.06085
```

Valliant implements percentile intervals this way, which should be equivalent to my percentile intervals:

```
 smho.boot.a <- as.svrepdesign(design = smho.dsgn,
                              type = "subbootstrap",
                              replicates = 500)
         # total & CI for EOYCNT based on RW bootstrap
 a1 <- svytotal( ̃EOYCNT, design = smho.boot.a,
                 na.rm=TRUE,
                 return.replicates = TRUE)
              # Compute CI based on bootstrap percentile method.
 ta1 <- quantile(a1$replicates, c(0.025, 0.975))
```

I'm looking for clarifications on

a. How to construct bootstrap CIs with survey package for statistics of interest
b. If my `withReplication` implementation of the bootstrap is correct

Answer (score 7):

The percentile stuff doesn't actually work with multistage survey data (or, at least, it isn't *known* to work (or, at least, it isn't known *to me* to work)). Survey bootstraps just estimate the variance.  You don't get the higher order accuracy for smooth functions that way, but you do get asymptotically the right variance.  To get asymmetric intervals you need to bootstrap some suitable function of the parameter, as `svyciprop` and `svyquantile` (and in a sense `svyglm`) do.

If you assume simple random sampling with replacement of clusters then you could make the percentile bootstrap and extensions work, but that's not a common structure for real-world surveys (and it doesn't really need the survey package)

I'm sure the maintainer of the package would be happy to implement a bootstrap that gave better asymmetric intervals and worked for multistage samples, if someone pointed out suitable references to him.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm working in a SRS/1-stage context, where it does seem they work OK. Using the survey package is helpful because implementing a) stratified sampling and b) FPC is non-trivial if just coding it up on your own. The example I gave using withReplicates and weighing the replications is my attempt to take advantage of the functionality of the package. I noticed this implementation in, I believe Valliant's latest book.. (Practical Tools for Designing ..) or Lohr's latest book. I need to check. Is it not correct?

Comment: Yes it was Valliant, I added a reference. Do you have a recommendation for getting asymmetric intervals for ratios? (Here, I use bootstrap + supply my function to withReplicates and pass the weights for use in calculating the statistic). That can be done for ratios of course.. but wasn't sure if there's a better way.

Comment: I'd try computing log ratios and then exponentiating the confidence intervals.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to do this in Survey?

svyratio(~I(log(numerator)), I(log(denominator))) is obviously not a good idea.

I need the log of the ratio not of the components.. But it's not clear how to apply a transform on the ratio object.

Comment: [This review paper from Mashreghi et al.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistics-surveys/volume-10/issue-none/A-survey-of-bootstrap-methods-in-finite-population-sampling/10.1214/16-SS113.full) summarizes what is known about various confidence interval methods for several types of bootstrap. Unfortunately, the answer is mostly that not much is known still.

Comment: The [generalized bootstrap](https://bschneidr.github.io/svrep/articles/bootstrap-replicates.html#generalized-survey-bootstrap) has some encouraging simulation results for the percentile method, based on [Bertail and Combris (1997)](https://ideas.repec.org/a/adr/anecst/y1997i46p49-83.html) and [Beaumont & Patak (2012)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1751-5823.2011.00166.x), although the latter only looks at Poisson sampling.

Comment: @unionfind: that would better as an additional question, so other people could find the answer, but `svycontrast` will give you the standard error of the log of your statistic and `confint` will then give a confidence interval that you can exponentiate.